# Opencv Java MatOfFloat4 object cannot be created via constructor

Tags: java, opencv

I've a class which has the following variable:

```
private MatOfFloat4 horizonLine = new MatOfFloat4();
```

which I later on pass into a function as follows:

```
Imgproc.fitLine(tmpPoints, horizonLine, Imgproc.CV_DIST_L1, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
```

However, I get an error saying that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24)
    at org.opencv.core.MatOfFloat4.<init>(MatOfFloat4.java:12)
    at obstacleDetector.HorizonDetector.<init>(HorizonDetector.java:327)
    at obstacleDetector.HorizonDetector.getInstance(HorizonDetector.java:59)
    at obstacleDetector.Detector.<clinit>(Detector.java:28)
```

which directs me to the initialization of the variable. Why can't OpenCV intialize this variable? What is wrong?

**P.S:** If it matters, the class which I place this variable, is a Singleton class:

```
public static HorizonDetector getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new HorizonDetector();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Same instance of the Horizon Detector-Singleton class already exists.");
        }
        return _instance;
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out that `MatOfFloat4` should be initialized via list or an array. So, I defined my horizonLine as a float array:

```
horizonLine = new float[4];
```

and later on passed it into the constructor as a parameter and it worked:

```
MatOfFloat4 tmpHorizonline = new MatOfFloat4(horizonLine);
Imgproc.fitLine(tmpPoints, tmpHorizonline, Imgproc.CV_DIST_L1, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
```